# How can I find the sup and inf of $m/n$ such that m,n are natural numbers and $m<2n$?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

In a problem set I found this problem:

Find the $\sup$ and $\inf$ of $\frac mn$ such that $m,n$ are natural numbers and $m<2n$.

All I could do is this:

Since $m$ and $n$ are natural numbers, we have $m/n > 0$.
And since $m<2n$ we have $\frac mn < \frac{2n}n = 2$, thus $\frac mn<2$.

I got stuck on showing that $2$ is the supremum rigorously.

The answer provided in the solutions sheet is not helping at all, it goes like this (in French, translated to English):

*Il est clair que $0 < \frac mn < 2$, et on peut facilement en déduire que $\sup = 2$ et que $\inf=0$.*

In english:

*It is obvious that $0<\frac mn<2$, from this we can easily deduce that  $\sup = 2$ and $\inf=0$*

Comment: Do you know the Archimedean property of  real numbers?

Comment: @Koro Yes, for every real number 'r' we can find a natural number 'n' such that 'n>r'.

Comment: The bounds alone do not give the values of inf and sup. They also have to be the best possible bounds. What we have to show is that we can get arbitary close to $0$ and also arbitary close to $2$.

Comment: @Koro I am curious. What is wrong about the above comment ? And what do you consider to be the Archimeadian property ?

Comment: @Peter: By Archimedean property, I had this in mind: For every $\epsilon\gt 0$, there is an $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $\frac 1n<\epsilon$.

Comment: @Koro OK, but this is basicalyy the same as saying that we can beat every real number $r$ with some natural number $n$ : If we assume $r>0$ (otherwise , $1$ does the job already), then your $\epsilon$ is simply $\frac{1}{r}$ and $\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$ is equivlent to $n>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ , hence to $n>r$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what your solution sheet is saying is straight up wrong. We cannot conclude,  just from the inequality $0<\frac mn < 2$, that $\sup =2$. You need some more steps and more assumptions.

---

To prove that $s$ is the supremum of a set $A$, you need to prove two things.

1. That $s$ is the upper bound of $A$.
2. That any number smaller than $s$ is **not** the upper bound of $A$.

Let $$A=\left\{\frac mn| m,n\in\mathbb N, m<2n\right\}$$

You already proved that $2$ is the upper bound of $A$. Now, you need to prove that any number smaller than $2$ is not the upper bound of $A$. You can start doing this by saying one of the most common phrases in calculus: **Let $\epsilon > 0$.

Now, you need to prove that $2-\epsilon$ is not an upper bound of $A$. You can do this by proving that there exists some element $a\in A$ such that $a>2-\epsilon$.

To do this, think about what property $a$ needs to fulfill. You know that $a=\frac mn$ for some pair $m,n$. You also know that $a>2-\epsilon$.

You can write this out a bit and get

$$\frac mn > 2-\epsilon\\
m > 2n - \epsilon n$$

and note that the deduction above goes both ways. In other words, if you can find some $m,n\in\mathbb N$ such that $m>2n-\epsilon n$, then you will also have $a=\frac mn > 2-\epsilon$.

However, you have one more limitation, and that is that if you want $\frac mn$ to be an element of $A$, then $m<2n$ must also be true. This means that $m$ must be some value that is greater than $2n-\epsilon n$ and smaller than $2n$.

So, the question remains, *can you find such a pair of values*?

**Hint**: Think about what happens to the interval $(2n-\epsilon n, 2n)$ when $n$ is very large.

Comment: When ϵ > 2, 2n-ϵn becomes negative, and since 2n is greater than 1, we can always find a value for m in the interval (2n−ϵn,2n). When ϵ<2 is causing me problems, if n=1  and ϵ = 1 we get this interval (1,2), so m must be a natural between 1 and 2, which is not possible!

Comment: @ShinobiSan But you don't need to limit yourself to $n=1$! You are completely free to choose any $n$ you want! The only thing you cannot choose is the value of $\epsilon$. Once that is selected, you can take any $n$ you want, and any $m$ you want.

Comment: OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOH yes of course, I am chosing  ϵ = 1, then I have to find two naturals m and n that satisfy 2n- ϵn < m < 2n, which is always possible (in this case we can take n=3 and m=4. Thank you!

Comment: @ShinobiSan whoah whoah! YOU CANNOT CHOOSE $\epsilon$!!!

Comment: @ShinobiSan You **have** some $\epsilon$. This value of $\epsilon$ is given and cannot be changed. Then, given that $\epsilon$ which you have **no** control over, you need to find some $m,n$ such that $2n-\epsilon n < m < 2n$.

Comment: Oops, I used the wrong vocabulary, I mean in the case where ϵ = 1, we can take n=3 and m=4. And no matter what ϵ is given (not chosen, I have no control over it) I can find another value for n and m such that 2n−ϵn<m<2n

Comment: @ShinobiSan Yes, if $\epsilon =1$, then $n=3, m=4$ is OK. But you still need to explain how you can find some $m,n$ for a *general* $\epsilon$.

Comment: @5xum: I realized the error in my answer so I deleted it. Thanks a lot for pointing out the error.

Comment: @Koro No problem, happens to everyone :).

Comment: Ok. Let $ϵ>0$, by the Archimedan property, there exists a natural number $n$ such that $ϵ<n$ and $n<2n$ so we can find an $n$ such that $ϵ<2n$, now I will try to solve the following inequality $2n-ϵn < 2n-2$ so that I will be able to take $m=2n-1$, solving the inequality I get $n>2/ϵ$ so I can take $n= \lceil2/ϵ \rceil$. Right?

Comment: @ShinobiSan Sort of. You are completely misusing the Archimedan property though. The sentence "By the archimedan property, there exists a natural number $n$ such that $\epsilon < 2$ and $n<2n$" is, logically speaking completely nonsensical. However, if you just remove that completely nonsensical sentence, the rest of the solutiov works perfectly well and is correct. Note that where you **actually** use the Archimedan property is when you define $n=\lceil 2/\epsilon\rceil$.

Comment: Of course, it can be reduced to: Let $ϵ>0$. I will solve the inequality $2n−ϵn<2n−2$ so that I will be able to take $m=2n−1$, solving the inequality I get $n>2/ϵ$ so I can take $n=⌈2/ϵ⌉$ and $m=2n-1$. If I am correct please tell me.

Comment: @ShinobiSan That looks better. You can, if you want, also replace the sentence "I can take $n=\lceil 2/\epsilon\rceil$" with "By the archimedan property, there exists some $n$ such that $n>2/\epsilon$" if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You have already noted that $2$  and $0$ are upper and lower bounds respectively for $S$.

Let's show that $2$ is indeed the supremum of $S$.
. Note that $2n-1<2n$ for any $\mathbb N$ and therefore $\frac{2n-1}{2n}\in S$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$. $\tag 1$

By Archimedean property of the reals, given any $\epsilon\gt 0, $ there exists $N\in \mathbb N$ such that $1/N\lt \epsilon\implies 2-\epsilon< 2-1/N=\color{blue}{\frac{2N-1}{2N}}<2$.  By $(1)$, the quantity in blue is in $S$ and hence by uniqueness of $\sup S$, it follows that $2$ is the supremum of $S$ (For if,suppose on the contrary $x:=\sup S<2$ then by the inequality established earlier, there must be some $m\in \mathbb N$ such that $2-(2-x)=x<\color{red}{\frac{2m-1}{2m}}<2$. But the quantity in red is in $S$ and this means that $S$ has an element larger than $\sup S$, which is a contradiction.).

$\inf S$ is the "greatest" lower bound for $S$. Now, if $\inf S=:y>0$, then by [Archimedean property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property) there is an $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $\frac 1n<y$ but $1/n\in S$ and hence $y$ is not a lower bound for $S$. This is a contradiction. Hence $y$ must be $0$.